# Save user input on HTML page using HTML5 web storage

Tags: javascript, html, web-storage

I am creating a crossword puzzle web app that pulls XML data from a server, parses the data with javascript and builds the puzzle on the page using the [canvas] tag. When a user selects a clue and types in a correct answer, letters are placed in the corresponding squares of the crossword puzzle.

Here's a snippet of the code that places the letters in the corresponding squares:

```
function answer() {
if (this.value != '') {
    var letters = this.value.split('');
    var correct = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName(node)[0].getAttribute('a').split('');
    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        if (letters[i]) {
            if (letters[i].toUpperCase() == correct[i]) {
                eval('ctx.drawImage(i'+letters[i].toLowerCase()+'b, '+((selected[i].id%15)*26)+', '+(Math.floor(selected[i].id/15)*26)+')');
                matrix[selected[i].id] = 1;
                numCorrect++;
            } else {
                matrix[selected[i].id] = 0;
            }
        }
    }       
    if (numCorrect == correct.length) {
        alert('Correct!');
        clearSelection();

    } else if (numCorrect == 0) {
        alert('Incorrect, try again.');
        document.getElementById('answer').value = '';
        document.getElementById('answer').focus();
    } else if (numCorrect != correct.length) {
        alert('Only some letters are correct.');
        clearSelection();
    }
    checkForWin();      
}
}
```

My question is, how do I save the state of the puzzle and the XML (using HTML5 web storage) so that the user can play offline and to prevent them from losing their progress in the event of a browser refresh?

Can anyone help me with this one, I am not very familiar with the HTML Web Storage API...but I hear that it is a valuable tool for web apps. Your advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Carlos

Answer (score 1):

You can save a JSON object or the state of your program inside html5 local storage by using the following javascript:

```
if(localStorage)
 localStorage.setItem("NAME", JSON/XML Object);
```

then you can fetch it later on by using

```
var savedGame = localStorage["NAME"];
```

One warning though, it will work on all browsers except for IE because they use something else as local storage.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I am still a bit lost when it comes to how to accomplish this. Just to clarify, could I simply enter the code above in my javascript then activate it with onClick in a button or onRefresh, for example? Or is there more to it? And can the "NAME" parameter be anything I choose?

Comment: Definitely! And yes, you can replace the name with whatever you want to name your your object. "NAME" is the key value.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the rest of your app depends upon being on HTML5 you might consider using a library like [Lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/) to wrap localStorage but also to provide alternative implementations for other browsers that had a storage mechanism, but not localStorage. If you do go with Lawnchair then I'd recommend pairing it with [lccache](https://github.com/JohnMunsch/lccache).

If you decide to skip Lawnchair and stay with just localStorage, then I'll suggest you pair it with [lscache](https://github.com/pamelafox/lscache). Both lscache and lccache are wrappers that reduce the API to simply:

value = l(c/s)cache.get("key");

l(c/s)cache.set("key", value);

l(c/s)cache.remove("key");

That's about as simple as it can get to save stuff, get it back out, etc. Plus, for stuff you only want to store for a while. When you put it into the cache with a set, you can specify how long until it expires.